# PostgreSql function slows down view

Tags: postgresql, view, functions

I am rewriting Sybase view to postgresql and encountered such problem.
Is there any way to improve performance of view with functions inside?
For example we have complex function

```
create function func1(pid integer)
returns char(20)
as $$
begin
... do stuf
return 'aaaa';
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

And create view with function

```
create view view_client
as
select code, name, func1(pid) from client;
```

Such view performs terrible slow, unless "func1" is removed from it. Postgresql probalby executes function for every row even if column is not used?
count(*) from view with 2M rows takes 2+ minutes, without "func1" it takes ~10sec.

Comment: What exactly does the function do? Can you define it as `stable` or even better as `immutable`?

Comment: function selects value from other table depending on input parameter. Select is complicated with a lot of "if" statements.

Comment: So far **stable** looks very promising

Comment: Unrelated, but: are you sure you want `char(20)`? That is almost always a bad choice.

Comment: In PostgreSQL, char(20) is stored as text except it's slower because it's character restricted (has a check), and it a waste of space (because it's lpad'ed). Moreover, if your spec doesn't call for the limitations and padding there is no point. You pay that *small* price even on the function-call level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an answer,

> What exactly does the function do? Can you define it as stable or even better as immutable? – a_horse_with_no_name 12 mins ago

[From the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html)

> **IMMUTABLE / STABLE / VOLATILE** These attributes inform the query optimizer
>   about the behavior of the function. At most one choice can be
>   specified. If none of these appear, VOLATILE is the default
>   assumption.
>
> - **IMMUTABLE** indicates that the function **cannot modify the database and
>     always returns the same result when given the same argument values**;
>     that is, it does not do database lookups or otherwise use information
>     not directly present in its argument list. If this option is given,
>     any call of the function with all-constant arguments can be
>     immediately replaced with the function value.
> - **STABLE** indicates that the **function cannot modify the database, and
>     that within a single table scan it will consistently return the same
>     result for the same argument values, but that its result could change
>     across SQL statements.** This is the appropriate selection for functions
>     whose results depend on database lookups, parameter variables (such as
>     the current time zone), etc. (It is inappropriate for AFTER triggers
>     that wish to query rows modified by the current command.) Also note
>     that the current_timestamp family of functions qualify as stable,
>     since their values do not change within a transaction.
> - **VOLATILE** indicates that the function value **can change even within a
>     single table scan, so no optimizations can be made.** Relatively few
>     database functions are volatile in this sense; some examples are
>     random(), currval(), timeofday(). But note that any function that has
>     side-effects must be classified volatile, even if its result is quite
>     predictable, to prevent calls from being optimized away; an example is
>     setval().
>
> For additional details see [Section 36.6](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html)

The real question is essentially, can you optimize away f(x)

- Over everything (mathematical purity)
- Over the same scan
- Never (uses IO or system calls)

A somewhat important note is that even in production applications you can sometimes lie and say `IMMUTABLE` and it's perfectly fine. Just be aware of the consequences.

Comment: Problem persists if **union all** is used, any ideas?